# Mongo Java: Set values and push to array with previous values in one command

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver, mongo-java

I want to push the previous state (if the values changed) during an `upsert` into an array `history` (atomar) but no matter what I try, I can't find a clean solution.

*Below you find simplified attempts:*

**Attempt 1: Use `$set` and `$concatArrays`**

```
final var timestamp = Document.parse(String.format("{$set: {timestamp: %d}}", time));
final var pointCount = Document.parse("{$set: {" +
            "data_point_count: {$ifNull: [{$add: [\"$data_point_count\", 1]}, 1]}   }}");

final var history = Document.parse(String.format("{$set: {" +
   "history: {$cond: {" +
      "if: {$eq: [\"$timestamp\", %d]}," +
      "then: \"$history\"," +               // no changes, keep untouched
      "else: {$concatArrays: [" +
         "{$ifNull: [\"$history\", []]}," + // without, history stays null

         // Bug: this adds an empty object on 1st upsert (insert)
         "[{timestamp: \"$timestamp\", data_point_count: \"$data_point_count\"}]" +
      "]}" +
   "}}" +
"}}", time));

final var update = Arrays.asList(setHistory, timestampUpdate, meanNinetyPercentileUpdateCommand, setDataPointCount);
// If I don't use Arrays.asList() commands like `$ifNull` are written into the database
//final var update = Updates.combine(setDataPointCount, setHistory); does not interpret the commands

final var options = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true);
targetCollection.updateOne(filter, update, options);
```

Problem:

- when the `upsert` is executed the first time (i.e. insert), an empty object is added to history: `[{}]`
- on subsequent updates, everything works: `[{}, {12345, 2}, {23456, 3}]`

**Attempt 2: Use `$set` and `$push`**

```
final var update = new Document();

final var set = new Document();
set.put("timestamp", time);
set.put("data_point_count", Document.parse("{$ifNull: [{$add: [\"$data_point_count\", 1]}, 1]}"));
update.put("$set", set);

update.put("$push", Document.parse("{history: {timestamp: \"$timestamp\", data_point_count: \"$data_point_count\"}}}"));

final var options = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true);
targetCollection.updateOne(filter, update, options);
```

Problem:

- Does not interpret commands like `\"$timestamp\"` and `$ifNull` and just writes e.g. `$ifNull` into the database.
- I cannot use `Arrays.asList()` or else I get the error: `Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$push'`, but without the `Arrays.asList` the commands are not executed but just written to the database, e.g. `data_point_count: {$ifNull: ...}`

**Question:**
How can I use one `upsert` command which:

- creates `history: []` or `history: null` or just no `history` field during insert
- when the timestamp changes in the `update` add the state before the update object to the `history` array without any empty objects (see attempt 1).

---

**Update (suggestion from @Gibbs):**

If I understood your suggestion correctly, it also adds an empty object when the upsert is executed the first time: `[{}, {12345, 2}, {23456, 3}]`

```
final var setHistory = Document.parse(String.format("{"+
    "$set: {"+
        "history: {"+
            "$cond: ["+
                // <Array condition goes here>
                "{"+
                    "$eq: [\"$timestamp\", %d]"+ // with eq => insert also adds an empty object
                    //"$ne: [\"$timestamp\", %d]"+ // Error: "input to $map must be an array not string"
                "},"+
                //True part (timestamp not changed: keep history)
                "{"+
                    "$map: {"+
                        "input: \"history\","+
                        "in: {"+
                            "$mergeObjects: ["+
                                "\"$$this\","+
                                "{"+
                                    "timestamp: \"$timestamp\"," +
                                    "mean_ninety_percentile: \"$mean_ninety_percentile\""+
                                "}"+
                            "]"+
                        "}"+
                    "}"+
                "},"+
                //False part (timestamp changed: add state to history)
                "{"+
                    "$concatArrays: [" +
                        "{ $ifNull: [\"$history\", []] }," +
                        "[" +
                            "{"+
                                "timestamp: \"$timestamp\"," +
                                "mean_ninety_percentile: \"$mean_ninety_percentile\""+
                            "}"+
                        "]" +
                    "]"+
                "}"+
            "]"+
        "}"+
    "}"+
"}", time));
```

---

**For clarification, the goal is the following state** after the 2nd `upsert` (i.e. 1 insert and 1 update):

```
collection = [
  {
     timestamp: 23456,
     data_point_count: 2,
     history: [
        {timestamp: 12345, data_point_count: 1}
     ]
  },...
]
```

Comment: I haven't provided you a direct answer but a way to achieve it. Please give a try and let me know.

Comment: I also added the "goal" state after 2 upsert commands, just for claification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same using `aggregate update`. But it is supported from mongo 4.2+.

```
db.collection.update({},
[{
$set: {
  timestamp: 12345,
  mean_ninety_percentile: 0.111,
  history: {
    $cond: [
      // <Array condition goes here>
      {
        $eq: [
          "$timestamp",
          12345
        ]
      },
      // True part (timestamp not changed: keep history)
      "$history",
      // False part (timestamp changed: add state to history)
      {
        $concatArrays: [
          {
            $ifNull: [
              "$history",
              []
            ]
          },
          [
            // add current state to history
            {
              timestamp: "$timestamp",
              mean_ninety_percentile: "$mean_ninety_percentile"
            }
          ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
}],
{
  upsert: true
})
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions (see the "Update (suggestion from @Gibbs):" part in the updated question) but cannot see an improvement to my attempt 1 (apart from readability). Or did I missunderstand what you mean with `$array` and `[element]` ?

Comment: Can you help me with a MongoPlayground with sample data, tried query?

Comment: I inserted it but it does not seem to work, it interprets $set but not e.g. $cond: https://mongoplayground.net/p/X9b8owrckHS

Comment: Please refer [this playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wWa7Y_xTr_h), You haven't selected update in the tool.

Comment: I updated your answer - this works in the play ground (https://mongoplayground.net/p/o2Fu-qLY4e1) but not when executed via Java (there the first history object is always empty). Anyways - I'll mark your answer as accepted as I decided to use another pipeline/collection structure for this use case. Adding history objects to an array does not seem like a good idea as theoretically, the document could grow larger than 16 MB with this. Thanks a lot for your input. I hope this helps others or future me :)